# SMS message disappear after SmsReceiver onReceive

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an SMS app. When I choose this app as default SMS app and when I receive a new SMS with this SmsReceiver code, following problems occurs:

1) I get 2 onReceive calls for each new SMS

2) SMS message removed from phone after exiting onReceive call. I can only access SMS message from this onReceive call and after that message disappears.

What's wrong with this code? Do I have to run some code to keep new SMS?

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("pdus")) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
            String senderNumber = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
            String text = sms.getMessageBody();
            long time = sms.getTimestampMillis();
            sendNotification(context, senderNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SmsListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".QuickResponseService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive 2 `onReceive` calls because you register for both [`SMS_DELIVER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#SMS_DELIVER_ACTION) (active default SMS app listener) and [`SMS_RECEIVED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) (passive sms listener) actions. Your receiver is not checking what kind of action your intent is for. I suggest deleting `SMS_RECEIVED` action.

Since you're developing a default SMS app you're responsible for saving (or discarding) any incoming/outgoing messages in persistent memory.

Recommended practice is using [`Telephony.Sms.Inbox`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Inbox) table in content provider to do so (note that only the default sms app is granted permission to write to that table; any other app that has sms permission only has read access to it):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, senderNumber);
values.put(Telephony.BODY, text);
context.getContentResolver().insert(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, values);
```